# ansible deprecated problem

Tags: linux, ansible

I have ansible 2.4.2.x running and an inventory file which has "ansible_ssh_host etc." params.Normally ansible_ssh_host must be ansible_host as it is deprecated. [deprecated](https://github.com/rhos-infra/infrared-common-libraries/commit/b8f99209d5a6af2ff986faa8712068a4b18bb14e) .

when I play with ansible_host parameter I get this

> "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_ssh_host'"}

Here is the latest doc.It is "ansible_host" and no mention of deprecated anymore.[ansible latest doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)

Comment: `grep` over all the files to see if the env is set in another place.
`grep 'ansible_ssh_host' . -R`

Comment: "ansible -i inventory myhost -m setup | grep ansible_ssh_host" gives no output. with "grep ansible_host" it is what I expect.I have my local "inventory" file.

Comment: paste the results of `ansible-config dump --only-changed`
Otherwise, mention any settings you have changed/added/removed in ansible.cfg (or using the `ANSIBLE_*` environment variables).

Comment: actually I did not change anything in my custon ansible.cfg file which make reference to my custom inventory file.In this I made change to make it compatible with current ansible version which ansible says they are deprecated for now.Is there a way to verify my custom inventory file runs with proper ansible version? what s happening is is so weird.